Personalizar header de un jTable en Java
Estoy tratando de cambiar el estilo del header de una tabla, pero no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal, parece ignorar el código o algo así. El caso es que el header se queda con el estilo por defecto de una tabla en java y únicamente cambia el color de la letra.
Acá dejo el código:
public HomeScreen() {
        initComponents();
        tbCoordenadas.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black",Font.PLAIN,18));
        tbCoordenadas.getTableHeader().setOpaque(true);
        tbCoordenadas.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tbCoordenadas.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        tbCoordenadas.setRowHeight(25);
        
    }

Termina teniendo un aspecto por default y no como espero. Agradecería mucho la ayuda. Por cierto, la tabla no es generada por código, sino como componente de Java
